# Django webapp does not set azure variables

Tags: django, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

Oke so my main issue is that my django backend that is deployed cannot read Azure env variables.

Context:
For context i am using github actions to deploy my application. The workflow makes a docker image out of a docker file, then pushes it to my docker registry. After that does the usual installing python packages needed for the app and making migrations for the database.

In my local enviroment i am using docker compose with a .env file and this works good, but now that i am deploying the app to azure in a docker container i get issues.

My main reason is because i do some logging in my settings.py and also i try to make a user in my database, but i get an error that it can't find my "key" which is correct because before the error i am printing some env values which are empty aswel.

```
root@905a7777498c:/usr/src/app# python manage.py createsuperuser
key openai None
key db name None
key db user None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 88, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 453, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 485, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 494, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/src/app/temujin/urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    from temujin_core import views_project, views_analysis, views_authentication
  File "/usr/src/app/temujin_core/views_analysis.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .gpt_utils import get_gpt_response, estimate_gpt_tokens
  File "/usr/src/app/temujin_core/gpt_utils.py", line 5, in <module>
    client = OpenAI()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openai/_client.py", line 92, in __init__
    raise OpenAIError(
openai.OpenAIError: The api_key client option must be set either by pa
```

ssing api_key to the client or by setting the OPENAI_API_KEY environment variable

I run this createsuperuser python command in my ssh connection of my webapp.

In my webapp i have all env's needed configured for my applicaiton to use them.

[image]

And i use those variables in my code with

```
client.api_key = os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY")

or

print("key openai", os.environ.get('OPENAI_API_KEY'))

print("key db name", os.environ.get('DATABASE_NAME'))

print("key db user", os.environ.get('DATABASE_USER'))
FROM python:3.8
```

My docker file if needed

```
# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Install SSH and other dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server \
    && echo "root:Docker!" | chpasswd \
    && mkdir /run/sshd

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container
COPY . /usr/src/app/

# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Collect static files
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --no-input


# Expose ports for SSH and your application
EXPOSE 2222 8000

# Copy startup script and SSH config
COPY startup.sh /usr/src/app/
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/startup.sh
COPY sshd_config /etc/ssh/

# Start SSH and your application
CMD ["/usr/src/app/startup.sh"]
```

If anyone knows what I am doing wrong exactly I would highly appreciate it. This is my first time setting up Azure or Django so I don't really know what i should be asking.

My github workflow file

```
name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - temujin-api

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1

      - name: Log in to Docker Registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          registry: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL }}
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          file: ./Dockerfile
          push: true
          tags: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL }}/temujin:${{ github.sha }}

      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL }}

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL }}

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
          slot-name: production
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
          images: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL }}/temujin:${{ github.sha }}
```

Comment: If you're using GitHub's CI/CD pipeline to build the docker image, the code above is probably executing in github, before pushing to azure. Which means it cannot access the keys specified in your azure console. You should add the keys in your GitHub Repository's Environment instead ! Visit : https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables

Comment: Hey @Khushal Thanks for your help! Could you maybe guide me where i should be ading the env variables? I have them as secrets in my github settings. So do i just add global env settings like

env:
 DB_NAME: ${{secrets.DB_NAME }}

But how will my docker image be built with those env's? Maybe i am not understanding it correctly yet.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @khushal for your insights, As khushal said we can access the keys specifying in GitHub Repository's Environment.

**GitHub Actions Workflow YAML File:**

- Save this file as `.github/workflows/main.yml` in the working repository.

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - temujin-api

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    env:
      DB_NAME: ${{ secrets.DB_NAME }}
      OPENAI_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.OPENAI_API_KEY }}
      # Add other environment variables as needed

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1

      - name: Log in to Docker Registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          registry: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL }}
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          file: ./Dockerfile
          push: true
          tags: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL }}/temujin:${{ github.sha }}

      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL }}

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL }}

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
          slot-name: production
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
          images: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL }}/temujin:${{ github.sha }}
```

**Dockerfile:**

- Check that you have a Dockerfile in the repository with instructions to build the Django app.

```
# Set environment variables
ENV DB_NAME=$DB_NAME
ENV OPENAI_API_KEY=$OPENAI_API_KEY

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container
COPY . /usr/src/app/

# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Collect static files
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --no-input

# Expose ports for your application
EXPOSE 8000

# Start your application
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

- The workflow sets environment variables (`DB_NAME`, `OPENAI_API_KEY`, etc.) using GitHub secrets. These secrets are securely stored in your repository's settings.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had already done all of these steps, but apparently if you access ssh console in your docker container for running python commands, it does not retain the same environment variables. So i had to export all variables in my ssh console before running python/django such as manage.py createsuperuser

Comment: Then you need to check environment variables are set globally or during the container initialization process rather than relying on per-session exports. This might involve modifying the Docker entrypoint or startup scripts to ensure that the environment variables are properly initialized and available to all sessions within the container.